# How much data is used on VPN?

Tags: vpn

The house I am purchasing does not have any internet options available besides using cell  phone service 4G network.  If I log on through VPN I'm wondering how much data I will be using since cell phone services now charge for data.  I would be connected to VPN for 8 hours a day, but for the most part, I would only be sending/receiving emails and occasionaly pulling data down from the company's reporting websites.  This can usually be accomplished very quickly and I'm off the internet.  80% of my day I am working on spreadsheets that I pull down from the company's network drives.

Comment: You would be using your vpn to do all of your browsing?

Answer (score 4):

The VPN link alone don't make any considerable additional traffic. Except for the initial handshake and some extra bytes per packet, there isn't much "talking" between the peers.

In fact, the use of VPN can optimize your traffic, since it's protocol supports [LZO compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Oberhumer), making any data passible of compression to be transferred compressed, using less bandwidth. Though you might have to check if this feature is enabled.

Comment: Effectively the question can't be answered better then this as the answer must be "it depends" - in this case probably by the number and size of the excel spreadsheets.